# Pandas df: retrieving the records that have cell value == float not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code and I can't figure out what to do to retrieve the row that I want.

I am trying to retrieve the row that has `device_id=16384035`. I tried both float and integer and also string there (since it tells me the column is object) but none worked

```
print(s_devices['Device ID'])
print(s_devices.columns)
print(s_devices.iloc[0,1])
print(type(s_devices.iloc[0,1]))
print(s_devices[['Device ID']==float(16384035)])
```

The above prints the below

```
0      16384035.0
1      17177488.0
2      16384036.0
3      17177489.0
4               0
          ...    
534    17746358.0
535    17746359.0
536    17746360.0
537    17746361.0
538    17746362.0
Name: Device ID, Length: 539, dtype: object
Index(['Serial Number', 'Device ID', 'Device Name'.....some keys removed from here],
      dtype='object')
16384035.0
<class 'float'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_540/2993650396.py in <module>
      3 print(s_devices.iloc[0,1])
      4 print(type(s_devices.iloc[0,1]))
----> 5 print(s_devices[['Device ID']==float(16384035)])

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3453             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3454                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3455             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3456             if is_integer(indexer):
   3457                 indexer = [indexer]

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: False
```

Comment: You are selecting the column incorrectly. You need to use `s_devices[s_devices['Device ID']==float(16384035)]`

Comment: damn. this is what happens if you do not stop when you are tired. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're indexing it wrong:

```
s_devices[['Device ID']==float(16384035)]
```

You create a boolean Series with the equality and index the DataFrame with it:

```
msk = s_devices['Device ID']==float(16384035)
out = s_devices[msk]
```

or as a one-liner:

```
out = s_devices[s_devices['Device ID']==float(16384035)]
```

Note that `['Device ID']==float(16384035)` evaluates to False. So what you're trying to do is: `s_devices[False]` which raises the KeyError since there's no column named `False`.